# Django - Displaying model data on Elasticsearch search result

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am making a booking website, and I have implemented elasticsearch. I got the search working just fine, but now I am kind of stuck on a problem.

What I'm trying to do is display the lowest price for the apartment the user has searched for, in the search results.

The prices are stored in the "ApartmentPrices" model :

```py
class ApartmentPrices(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete="models.CASCADE", related_name="price")
    price_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    price_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.apartment.title
```

This is my document and view for the actual search :

search view :

```py
def search(request):
    apartments = Apartment.objects.all()
    q = request.GET.get('q')

    if q:
        apartments = ApartmentDocument.search().query("match", title=q)
    else:
        apartments = ''

    return render(request, 'search/search_elastic.html', {'apartments': apartments, "q": q, })
```

elasticsearch document:

```py
apartments = Index('apartments')


@apartments.document
class ApartmentDocument(Document):
    class Django:
        model = Apartment

        fields = [
            'title',
            'id',
            'bedrooms',
            'list_date',

        ]
```

I have tried passing in apartment_id to the search view, but I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please ? How do I access model data from a ES query ?

Thank you !

Comment: did you get this to work? are you using elasticsearch-py or elasticsearch-dsl?

Answer (score 0):

If you already stored the prices in elastic you can make a second request as elastic is not relational. You have to search for all the prices related with the list of apartment_ids returned.
If you stored prices with apartment_id field you can make a "terms" query with all the ids.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html

You'll get 2 result set one with the apartments (your actual one) and one with the prices for the apartments. You need to loop through to display the correct data.

------Comment------

I think there's a problem is in your search view you make a search in your database:
apartments = Apartment.objects.all()

then you take a parameter q (that I expect to be the title of an apartment) 
q = request.GET.get('q')

and you make a search in elastic and overwrite the apartments which is a database result with a json results... you will have problem to handle your result in your template.

You first need to remove the first call to the database and use only elastic in your view otherwise it will be a pain to handle 2 kinds one objects as you can have property on the database model object that you will may not define in the elastic one. 
We use elastic from nearly 7 years and we had hard time to manage views with 2 kind of models. Now we mainly use elastic in the view, after it depends on your usage, but don't melt the 2 models, prefer one.
In your search if you plan to use elastic model remove the database call if in another one you use database don't use elastic.